# Shortest path algorithm for differently weighted bidirectional graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am searching for a way of finding the shortest path for a differently weighted bidirectional graph. The graph is not complete, almost all the edges are bidirected and the weight from A to B is not the same as from B to A. Only two of the vertices, the source, and the target, will have only the mono-directed weighted edge connecting them.

All the algorithms' examples I found (Dijkstra, Floyd–Warshall etc.) are covering the situation when the weight from A to B is the same as from B to A.

Comment: No, they all cover the more general case.